# AutoMapper test fails on implicit widening conversion in TeamCity build but not locally

Tags: visual-studio-2013, teamcity, automapper

I have the following AutoMapper configuration:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()                
            .ForMember(dest => dest.InitiatorUserAccountUID, opt => opt.UseValue(0));
```

`InitiatorUserAccountUID` is of type `long`. The `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` unit test passes locally, but fails on TeamCity with the following error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: The following property on
>   System.Int64 cannot be mapped: 
>       InitiatorUserAccountUID

When I cast 0 to long explicitly in the configuration, the test passes in both places. What can be causing this?

**TeamCity build info:**

- Runner type: Visual Studio (sln)
- Visual Studio: Microsoft Visual
  Studio 2013
- Runner Type for test step: MSTest
- Path to MSTest.exe: MSTest 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add `[DeploymentItem("AutoMapper.Net4.dll")]` to the test class. Everything works fine now.

Comment: This is an irritating problem with automapper. An alternative is to reference a class in `AutoMapper.Net4.dll` in your test project somewhere, eg `var type = typeof (NullableConverterFactory);//means AutoMapper.Net4.dll will be referenced and copied to output test folder.` 
see https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/318 for more